# Remove and Add Attribute id using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have menu in my website and I want to Remove and Add Attribute id using jQuery based on Different Pages.
**My Code :**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="current"><a href="">Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="Category.aspx">Category</a></li>
    <li><a href="SubCategory.aspx">SubCategory</a></li>
    <li><a href="Area.aspx">Area</a></li>
    <li><a href="Feedbacks.aspx">Feedbacks</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here, on Home Page, id 'current' is set to first li. Now, when user visits Category, I want to remove id current from Users and set id to Category.
How to do this ?

Comment: look for JQuery docs for `removeAttr` also `.prop` **but** `id` is the unique identifier for html, why would you want to remove id from your html. `:)` just a thought. API: https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: @Tats_innit, its like Respected Menu will be highlighted based on Page Visit so I want to remove id from one and set to another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li#current').removeAttr("id"); //remove previously added id
    var loc = $(location).attr('href'); //get current location
    $('#nav a').filter(function () { //filter a tag 
        return this.href == loc;//whose link is pointing to current location
    }).parent().attr('id', 'current'); //add id to parent li
});
```

Comment: it is setting id perfectly, but don't know with setting id to current menu, it also keeps adding id to users.aspx

Comment: @JeetenParmar because it's `href` is blank `<a href="">` .What is your home page link .? `home.aspx` ??

Comment: users.aspx is home page. My menus are in master page.

Comment: @JeetenParmar change your markup and set `<a href="users.aspx">`  it will work .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('li').removeAttr('id');
        $(this).attr('id','current');
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/rq9UB/610/)

Comment: But `current` is not an id.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice. Thanks I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//$('#nav li').each(function(){
    $('#current').removeAttr('id');
    $('li:active').attr('id','current');
//}
```

Comment: here, it is removing id for sure. But it is not setting id to current menu.

Comment: yup, it sets id to last menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nav li').click(function() {
        $('li#current').removeAttr("id");
        $(this).attr('id' , 'current');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
$('#nav li').click(function(){
  $('#current').removeAttr('id');
  $(this).attr('id','current');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(window.location.pathname) {
    case 'Category.aspx':
        $("#nav").find('#current').attr('id','');
        $('#nav').find('a[href="Category.aspx"]').attr('id', 'current');
    break;
    case 'SubCategory.aspx':
        $("#nav").find('#current').attr('id','');
        $('#nav').find('a[href="SubCategory.aspx"]').attr('id', 'current');
    break;
    case 'Area.aspx':
        $("#nav").find('#current').attr('id','');
        $('#nav').find('a[href="Area.aspx"]').attr('id', 'current');
    break;
    case 'Feedbacks.aspx':
        $("#nav").find('#current').attr('id','');
        $('#nav').find('a[href="Feedbacks.aspx"]').attr('id', 'current');
    break;

}
```